# Equivalent to CMD-clicking on a webpage title in Safari 8 on Yosemite

Tags: finder, macos, safari

In previous versions of Safari one could CMD-click on the webpage title at the top of Safari's window and get a menu with the website's folder hierarchy.

For example if you're at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask, clicking on the title would give you a menu with the following items:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/

allowing you to quickly navigate the website in question. Finder still has that feature if you want to see it in action. Just go to a folder, then CMD-click on that folder's name or icon in the title bar.

I liked that feature, however, it seems to have been removed in Safari 8. What I want to ask is, is there a way to restore it? A keyboard shortcut I've missed perhaps?

Comment: Update the download: The popover now  close when the url clicked is not the current one. This also allows it to refresh when you go to a new page using it.

Comment: The extension can now use the update/auto update feature in Safari. This starts from version 1.0.2  so if you have version 1.  Please re download it from the link and then you do not need to keep checking back here for changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could not find any thing to re enable this.

So I built a quick Safari Extension to give me something that would give me a list.

I am posting the link [here Hierarchy List](http://www.markosx.com/thecocoaquest/download/1492/)

And may repost with a how to make one when I get a little time.

---

[image]

---

---

[image]

---

update*
Update the download: The popover will now  close when the url clicked in the list is not the current one. This also allows it to refresh when you go to a new page using it.

---

**update** 2*

**The extension can now use the update/auto update feature in Safari. This starts from version 1.0.2  so if you have version 1.  Please re download it from the link and then you do not need to keep checking back here for changes.**

---

Update 3. Version 1.0.6

[image]

The Extension ui now has a Dark mode And Light Mode. You can change them in the Extensions preferences. ( images above have been changed to show this)

---

Note Although Safari extension can be set to Auto Update. I find that they only do when I actually click on the updates button in the Extensions preferences.

[image]

So if you have a version 1.0.2 upwards you can make sure the updates happen by doing this.

I also suggest you relaunch Safari. After any Extensions are updated.

Comment: Very nice! Is this on GitHub/etc?

Comment: I have never really put anything up there. But it's an idea..

Comment: Did a slight update just correct a misspelling for the product link in the Extension preferences that should go to my site.

Comment: Thank you for the extension and the updates, it's very much appreciated. One minor quibble I have is that the version number displayed in Safari's extension list remains 1.0.0b even for the latest version.

Comment: @Mr.Landsman Can you quit safari and see if it shows the right version. Safari and it's extensions seem to have this oddity.

Comment: I did and it shows the right version now (1.0.2). Thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Landsman Great.

Comment: @Mr.Landsman check out the update3 in my Answer

Comment: @markhunte I learned to do that while waiting for AgileBits to update their 1Password extension with retina display support a while back :)

Comment: @Mr.Landsman , Yer a bit annoying.. let me know what you think of the dark mode :-)

Comment: @markhunte I like the colors better but the dark grey is more common on web pages which can lead to contrast problems. Also, the white text under light grey highlight is difficult to read. [Here's an example](http://imgur.com/8lM5JgR).

Comment: @Mr.Landsman ,thanks for the feed back it's is supposed to go to black as you hover but does not until you are right over the text.. I am still working on it :-)